# CreateObject("Wscript.Shell") globally does not work

Tags: windows, vbscript, windows-7

I am trying to make a function that runs commands like this:

```
Set fso = CreateObject ("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set stdout = fso.GetStandardStream (1)
print runCommand("git --help")

function runCommand(commandStr)
    set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
    Set objExec = objShell.Exec(commandStr)

    Do Until objExec.Status
        Wscript.Sleep 10
    Loop

    runCommand = objExec.StdOut.ReadAll()
end function

sub print(str)
    stdout.WriteLine str
end sub
```

That works fine, but then I want to use the objShell at a higher level, so then I decide to make objShell global:

```
set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Set fso = CreateObject ("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set stdout = fso.GetStandardStream (1)
print runCommand(objShell.CurrentDirectory)
print runCommand("git --help")

function runCommand(commandStr)
    Set objExec = objShell.Exec(commandStr)

    Do Until objExec.Status
        Wscript.Sleep 10
    Loop

    runCommand = objExec.StdOut.ReadAll()
end function

sub print(str)
    stdout.WriteLine str
end sub
```

However, now when I run it I get the error:

```
WshShell.Exec: Access is denied.
```

And it references the line `set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")`. If I try to make two different variables objShell and objShell2 I get the same error. How do I resolve this?

Comment: In this case you need to get rid of "set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell") " at the begin of the function! Don't do it twice!

Comment: @duDE sorry that was a type-o. removed. The behavior still fails. And I missed the print function which I also added.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to replicate your issue locally I found that the scope of `WScript.Shell` is not at fault.

Try this and it will most likely work *(notice the commented out line)*;

```vb
set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Set fso = CreateObject ("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set stdout = fso.GetStandardStream (1)
'print runCommand(objShell.CurrentDirectory)
print runCommand("git --help")

function runCommand(commandStr)
    Set objExec = objShell.Exec(commandStr)

    Do Until objExec.Status
        Wscript.Sleep 10
    Loop

    runCommand = objExec.StdOut.ReadAll()
end function

sub print(str)
    stdout.WriteLine str
end sub
```

The `Access Denied` error appears to be related to calling `objShell.CurrentDirectory`.

The issue is you are trying to pass the current directory to `objShell.Exec()` and it doesn't know how to execute it *(after all it's not an application)*.

Here is an example in it's simplest form;

```
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Exec("C:\")
```

Output:

```
WshShell.Exec: Access is denied.
```

If you just wanted to output the current directory using your script you probably wanted to use

```vb
print objShell.CurrentDirectory
```

instead.

Comment: ahh...yes, that works! - I think I am doing something dumb... I am trying to use the output of objShell.CurrentDirectory in my call function, and I think there must be a resource double usage going on here. I have split the this up now and it works great : ). Its hard with out a decent IDE :o

Comment: @code_fodder yeah you where trying to pass `objShell.CurrentDirectory` through your `runCommand()` function which will error as `objShell.Exec()` won't know what to do with it.